# Single character keywords/operators with no spaces with listings package

Tags: listings, color, keywords

I want to add a very simple macro language to `listings`. It uses single-letter keywords/operators, with no whitespace between. I can't see how to make keywords that don't require some kind of separator between them, i.e. I can make keywords for `G`, `H`, `I`, and they will colorise in `G H I` but not `GHI`.

Macro language is:

- `0`–`9`, `A`–`F` are numbers
- `G`–`Z` and `,.<>;:` are keywords/operators
- `"…"` are quoted strings
- all other chars are ignored (and I would like to colorise them grey)

So a valid macro might be

```
G2R67S4F, X 5A. ODC>4ET"A quoted string"P
```

in the above, I want `G` `R` `S` `X` `,` `.` `>` `T` `P` to be colorised as keywords and
`67` `DC` `4E` colorised as numbers.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

A straight-forward way of doing this would be to use [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)' capability to perform `literate` replacements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\colorlet{numbercol}{blue}% Colour of numbers: 0-9 and A-F
\colorlet{keywordcol}{red}% Colour of keywords: G-Z and ,.<>;:
\colorlet{stringcol}{green}% Colour of strings: "..."

\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  morestring=[b][\color{stringcol}]",
  showstringspaces=false,
  literate = *{0}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 0}}}1 % numbers
              {1}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 1}}}1
              {2}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 2}}}1
              {3}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 3}}}1
              {4}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 4}}}1
              {5}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 5}}}1
              {6}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 6}}}1
              {7}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 7}}}1
              {8}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 8}}}1
              {9}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 9}}}1
              {A}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily A}}}1
              {B}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily B}}}1
              {C}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily C}}}1
              {D}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily D}}}1
              {E}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily E}}}1
              {F}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily F}}}1
              {G}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily G}}}1 % keywords
              {H}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily H}}}1
              {I}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily I}}}1
              {J}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily J}}}1
              {K}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily K}}}1
              {L}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily L}}}1
              {M}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily M}}}1
              {N}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily N}}}1
              {O}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily O}}}1
              {P}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily P}}}1
              {Q}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily Q}}}1
              {R}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily R}}}1
              {S}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily S}}}1
              {T}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily T}}}1
              {U}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily U}}}1
              {V}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily V}}}1
              {W}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily W}}}1
              {X}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily X}}}1
              {Y}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily Y}}}1
              {Z}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily Z}}}1
              {,}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily ,}}}1
              {.}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily .}}}1
              {<}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily <}}}1
              {>}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily >}}}1
              {;}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily ;}}}1
              {:}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily :}}}1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
G2R67S4F, X 5A. ODC>4ET"A quoted string"P
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

`literate=[*]<replacement item> ... <replacement item>` works in the way that each `<replacement item>` takes the form `{<search>}{<replace>}{<width>}`, where `<search>` is replaced with `<replace>` and takes up the width of `<width>` characters. The optional `*` applies the `<replacement item>`s to only non-string entries.

You can adjust the colours to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that works perfectly!

I put it in a language define:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{BL233} {   
   basicstyle = \ttfamily,
   morestring=[b][\color{stringcol}]",
   showstringspaces=false,
   literate = *{0}{{\textcolor{numbercol}{\ttfamily 0}}}1 % numbers
 }
```

Also lets me define a second language expansion that explains the single letter macro commands: eg this expand S to Start

`{S}{{\textcolor{keywordcol}{\ttfamily S}}{\textcolor{meaningcol}{\ttfamily tart}}}5`

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments or accept answer. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).